# Can I put a class definition into __init__.py?

Tags: python

I have a package with a class structure similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2liw.png).
`Base` class is a typical, simple parent class for a few separate hierarchies.

My package layout looks like this:

```
__init__.py (empty)
base.py
ab.py
cd.py
ef.py
```

Is it a good idea or good practice to put `Base` class into `__init__.py` instead of creating separate module just for one class? In this way I wouldn't need to import it each time in modules.

Comment: I'd leave it in base.py but write something like `from base import Base` into the `__init__.py` such that you can then directly import `Base` from *my_package* like `from my_package import Base`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is perfectly fine and a more flexible approach to leave it in `base.py`. Also note that **the primary use of __init__.py is to initialize Python packages** and not to hold content.

To avoid having to import the module each time you can write something like

```
# in __init__.py
from .base import Base
```

into the `__init__.py` such that you can directly import `Base` from my_package:

```
# some script
from my_package import Base
```

This is a **common approach to make objects available at the package level**.

For more info about the `__init__.py` file check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: So what is the downside of putting classes in `__init__.py`?

Comment: @user42723 There's nothing inherently wrong with doing that, but some may find it messy or poor style. A key insight here is that Python packages **are** modules - they're represented by the same `module` type, not even a subtype.

Comment: For example, the [standard library defines a whole bunch of stuff directly in the `__init__.py` of the `collections` package](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/collections/__init__.py). This is a simple way of working with the fact that `collections` was a simple module originally, before `collections.abc` was added. Similarly, [`json`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/json/__init__.py) defines the main function-based interface in `__init__.py`, while shuffling the support classes off to separate files.

Comment: @user42723 The problem is that it treats some classes differently from others for no good reason...unless you put all the classes in the init file (which starting off this way also encourages).  Everything in one file leads to the usual problems: merge hell, readability, finding what you are looking for.  A sprinkling of files in __init__ and the rest elsewhere makes it hard to infer whether a class exists in a package or not looking at files and so you have to find classes using multiple, arbitrarily different search techniques in large projects.

Comment: You might have a reason to treat a class differently but this is rare...for example, a class that is a base class of all other classes in the package might make sense.