# How can I implement a python module with only one layer of access

Tags: python, module, directory

I want to implement a python module that I can import without multiple namespace layers.  For example, I would like to create a module that I can use as follows:

```
import sound

sound.echofilter(args...)
sound.reversefilter(args...)
```

In the examples and documentation I have seen, I cannot see how to do this.  The examples from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) have the following:

```
sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              echo.py
```

Which requires

```
import sound.effects.echo
sound.effects.echo.echofilter(args...)
```

While I can skip the outer and inner packages (sound and effects) and just have one layer of directories, I still have the extra layer of the file preceding the function, such as:

```
sound.echo.echofilter(args...)
sound.echo.reversefilter(args...)
```

Alternatively, I could just have one file, `sound.py` with `echofilter` and `reversefilter` both implemented in it, and not have any  directories.  However, for the sake of organising my code, it would be nice to have them in separate files and in a directory.

Is this possible with one layer of namespace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I put a class definition into \_\_init\_\_.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740935/can-i-put-a-class-definition-into-init-py)—not that I think you should feel pressured to have `__init__.py` have **only** `from .… import …` in it.

Comment: As a side note: Python supports aliasing imports. `import sound.effects.echo as sound` -> `sound.echofilter(x)`