# Best practices for top level __init__.py imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When a package becomes large, it can be hard to remember where things are, and dot-paths to the object we want can be cumbersome. One way that authors seem to address this is to bring references to the "best of" objects to the top, though there code can actually live several package levels below.

This allows one to say:

```py
from pandas import wide_to_long
```

instead of

```py
from pandas.core.reshape.melt import wide_to_long
```

But what are the ins and outs of doing this, and the best practices around the method? Doesn't loading the top `__init__.py` with many imports (in order to make them available at the top level) mean that any import of a single object of the package suddenly takes much more memory than needed - since everything mentioned in the `__init__.py` is automatically loaded?

Yet, packages do it. See, for example, what can be imported from top level `numpy` or `pandas` below (code to run your own diagnosis can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/thorwhalen/21aea71db50bff0e2bc934b0625d0754)).

```
$ python print_top_level_diagnosis.py numpy
--------- numpy ---------
599 objects can be imported from top level numpy:
  19 modules
  300 functions
  104 types

depth   count
0   162
1   406
2   2
3   29
4   1

$ python print_top_level_diagnosis.py pandas
--------- pandas ---------
115 objects can be imported from top level pandas:
  12 modules
  55 functions
  40 types

depth   count
0   12
3   37
4   65
5   1
```

Comment: I think it depends on the project. Some simple ones may need to load resources at the entry-level init but other larger projects should probably remain modular and only import when needed or have the developer import a module within the package like package.module1.module2. Django is pretty big and it uses the many dot functionality. I prefer this because it means I know where I'm importing from

Comment: Related: [Can I put a class definition into __init__.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47740935/6862601)

Comment: Memory is really not a concern here. Usually, in any case, most of a module/package is loaded into memory, you can't just pick and choose single objects. What changes is *what objects are available in what namespace*

Comment: Some of the best practices are discussed in this answer by the most amazing Aaron Hall: [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710527/6862601).

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a more philosophical question since there's no hard or fast ruleset that's used, so take my opinion with a grain of salt.

I like the phrase "API encourages behavior". Part of the behavior you want to encourage is the primary use case, the main ins and outs of your API. So for something like `pandas`, `DataFrame` and `Series` are naturally exposed in the root __init__.py file. For larger packages like `scipy`, __init__.py files are used in sub-packages because the use case for the package is too broad to expose everything at the top.

Keep in mind that not *everything* needs to be exposed in an __init__.py file. Keeping your more power-user features out of an __init__.py file both protects new users from tumbling down a rabbit hole and communicates that there's something special going on when you see an import from deep within a package.

For example:

```py
# Anyone will immediately associate this import with a standard use case
from pandas import DataFrame

# Most people, even seasoned pandas users, will take a second to question why this import exists
from pandas.core.internals.ops import operate_blockwise
```

Lastly, using __init__.py files is helpful for keeping your code organized and protecting users (including internal users!) from restructuring. It doesn't matter where `DataFrame` is actually defined, because the established usage promises that `DataFrame` will be a top-level `pandas` import. This can be really handy for growing projects, but just like any interface, you need to be diligent about honoring established interfaces, even if it's just the location of an import.

In summary:

- Encourage behavior by exposing the main parts of your API
- Protect novices from more advanced features
- Organize your code

Answer (score 0):

All methods have pros and cons and in `__init__.py` you pretty much do what you want. Having said that, an important guideline is that `__init__.py` should never have any "side effects". This means that it shouldn't do anything else than declaring the namespace. Having side effects can really confuse the users of your library or even become a security risk.

Example `__init__.py` in module called "mylibrary":

```py
import requests

result = requests.get("URL TO SOME VIRUS")
...
```

In this example, running `import mylibrary` actually downloads something (or sends information).

If you leave `__init__.py` free of any side effects there are a few considerations. The first is load times. Every time your library is imported Python will go through, and run(!), all `__init__.py` files it can find. This means that if your file contains a slow operation, like for example loading a large file or a large number of external dependencies, your library can actually become really slow to load. You can work around this by wrapping expensive calls in a function and exposing the function, but it's still something to consider.

Another thing to consider is versioning of your library. If you move a file to a different folder, do all of your users or yourself need to update all import statements? If you look at the `pandas` library you'll see that they created `api` submodules (e.g. `pandas.core.api`) which contain all the public functions/classes/etc. All imports are done from the `api` submodules and this ensures that after a change, only 1 location needs to update the import statements and everything will keep working.