# Making functions available at `package/__init__.py`, how can I prevent module internal code from importing from the top level `__init__.py`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, circular-dependency, flake8

I'm writing a data manipulation package based on python pandas. For the part which has a [functional style](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html), I would like to make my package hierarchy flatter. Currently functions need to be imported using calls such as:

```
from package.module.submodule import my_function
```

The proposed change would make it possible to import

```
from package import my_function
```

To achieve this, functions and other objects would be imported into `package/__init__.py` so that they are available in the top level name space. This is how pandas does it, for example [pandas/`__init__.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/__init__.py#L109) makes it possible to import

```
from pandas import DataFrame
```

When in fact, the DataFrame class is defined inside [pandas.core.frame](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py#L465). You would normally have to import it like this: `from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame`, but since it's imported in the top level `__init__.py` it's made available at the top level.

Making functions available as top level imports:

- would expose a flat hierarchy for users and would make it easier to use the package
- but internally (in the package code) we should not import from `package/__init__.py` directly to avoid creating circular references.

  - [Searching for from+pandas+import](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/search?p=5&q=from+pandas+import) It seems that pandas always avoids importing from the top level (except test scripts which do use from pandas import DataFrame). I don't know how to enforce this.
  - Maybe this tool can be helpful: [pylint-forbidden-imports](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-forbidden-imports/),
  - or rather [flake8-tidy-imports](https://github.com/adamchainz/flake8-tidy-imports) since we are using black and flake8 as a pre commit hook. flake8-tidy-imports makes it possible to define which imports are forbidden. It seems it applies to the whole package though, and not to a specific location in the package.

Related questions

- [Best practices for top level __init__.py imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801276/best-practices-for-top-level-init-py-imports)
- [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python/35710527#35710527)

  - the accepted answer mentions "I personally write an `__all__` early in my development lifecycle for modules so that others who might use my code know what they should use and not use."

Comment: 2c: this seems like a bad idea but also asking for tool suggestions on SO is off topic as it leads to spammy/advertisery answers

Comment: @AnthonySottile I am asking for advice on how to expose functions as top level imports. I added the link to 2 related questions which seem to show that this is not necessarily a bad idea.

Comment: your question is "how can I prevent", tagged [flake8], and listed some tools -- how is this not a "please suggest to me a tool" question?

Comment: At this stage, I am not even sure I am asking the right question. I would like to know if this is a good approach. I think it is because other packages such as pandas are doing it. Then if I should use the tool or not and how to use the tool.

Comment: well then that would be "opinion based" and also closed :)

Comment: @AnthonySottile I'm here to learn. Could you please point out a place that explains why this is a bad idea?

Comment: it's a whole load of complexity and makes it way too easy to introduce cycles (even if you don't "import from `__init__`" it's going to be implicitly imported any time you deal with any module in your hierarchy.  all to save a few characters of keyboard-typing?

Comment: It seems like the functionality you want is served by the post in your [2nd related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python/35710527#35710527). Do you mean you want a way to ensure developers working on your package don't break the "top level import" rule?

Answer (score 3):

I think the concern you are expressing is the fact that "importing a sub-module" and "importing a sub-module during the import of a module" are not the same thing. For example, writing this in ipython:

```
from module.sub.file import func
```

and writing this from within the `module` package

```
from module.sub.file import func
```

do not do the same thing (even though they look the same). This is because if `module` has already started its' initialization; then subsequent calls to a sub-module will not re-initialize `module` nor does `module` need to have finished initializing before calling its' submodules. This is very similar to how class inheritance works too.

This means that it is perfectly valid for a package to pull various functions from all of its' sub-modules, while each of its' sub-modules can explicitly import from each other through the package itself without causing an infinite loop. This is by design. Example,

```
module
    __init__.py
        from .sub1.file1 import func1
        from .sub2.file2 import func2
    sub1
        __init__.py
        file1.py
            from module.sub2.file2 import func2
            def func1(x):
                return func2(x)+x
    sub2
        __init__.py
        file2.py
            def func2(x):
                return x+1
```

Here the sub-module `sub1` is dependent on `sub2`. The line `from module.sub2.file2 import func2` normally means

1. execute `module/__init__.py` and load from namespace `sub2`
2. execute `module/sub2/__init__.py` and load from namespace `file2`
3. execute `module/sub2/file2.py` and load from namespace `func2`

but during a call of `from module import func1`, when we reach the line in `file1.py` of `from module.sub2.file2 import func2` we have either already ran or in are in the middle of running `module/__init__.py` and `module/sub/__init__.py`. This means that line more like does:

1. `module/__init__.py` is currently being executed...skip
2. `module/sub2/__init__.py` was already loaded...skip
3. execute `module/sub2/file2.py` and load from namespace `func2`

In general, if `module/__init__.py` is currently being executed, then additional calls to that statement will simply be skipped. You can quite literally `import module` itself and it will be outright skipped even though it hasn't finished loading itself. Add some print statements

```
module
    __init__.py
        print('start init module')
        from .sub1.file1 import func1
        from .sub2.file2 import func2
        print('end init module')
    sub1
        __init__.py
        file1.py
            print('loading module from file1.py')
            import module
            print('done loading module from file1.py')
            from module.sub2.file2 import func2
            def func1(x):
                return func2(x)+x
    sub2
        __init__.py
        file2.py
            def func2(x):
                return x+1
```

Now run `from module import func1`:

```
start init module
loading module from file1.py
# Notice that nothing is printed here, meaning module/__init__.py was not run again, 
# even though we explicitly wrote "import module", additionally "module" wasn't 
# even finished executing it's own __init__.py file. 
done loading module from file1.py
end init module
```

This is awesome from a design perspective. It means that `sub2` could have very well been a package completely separate from `module` but dependent on `module`. Then at some point, someone was like, "lets drop that indpendent package as sub-module to our `module` package". The entire folder is just dropped in (without changing any code) and then `module` can import from it like it is a local sub-package without any care of creating an import loop by accident, even though the sub-package depends on other parts of module itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is exactly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) and solved by using intra-package referencing. You refer to the sub-modules using

```
from ..frame import DataFrame
```

instead of using

```
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
```

I can see it also worked for people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder).

This type of referencing is used normally and this is an example by Baidu team in their OCR engine to [import all modules](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.4/__init__.py).

Stick to your idea because referring to other paths is harsh if your users are beginners.

Answer (score -1):

I've searched through the pandas GitHub repository and was unable to find a pre-commit hook that addresses your specific problem, so I adapted the [use-pd_array-in-core](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ce3bac9af43838c7d690ee86e9bec4976a3303e3/scripts/use_pd_array_in_core.py) hook from the [pandas repository](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas).

My test setup has the following folder structure (excluding the `.git` folder):

```
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module
│   │   └── submodule.py
│   └── second_module
│       └── submodule.py
├── .pre-commit-config.yaml
└── scripts
   └── import_from_submodules.py
```

The `.pre-commit-config.yaml` contains

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: import-from-submodules
        name: Import from appropriate submodules
        language: python
        entry: python scripts/import_from_submodules.py package
        files: ^package/
        types: [python]
```

and the the `import_from_submodules.py` file contains

```py
"""
Check that all imports reference the correct submodule and not import directly
from __init__.py, even though that is technically possible.

This is meant to be run as a pre-commit hook - to run it manually, you can do:

    pre-commit run import-from-submodules --all-files

"""

from __future__ import annotations

import argparse
import ast
import sys
from typing import Sequence


class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, package_name: str, path: str) -> None:
        self.package_name = package_name
        self.path = path
        self.error_message = (
            "{path}:{lineno}:{col_offset}: "
            f"Don't import from {self.package_name}, "
            f"import from {self.package_name}.submodule instead\n"
        )

    def visit_Import(self, node: ast.Import) -> None:
        if any(module.name == self.package_name for module in node.names):
            msg = self.error_message.format(
                path=self.path, lineno=node.lineno, col_offset=node.col_offset
            )
            sys.stdout.write(msg)
            sys.exit(1)
        super().generic_visit(node)

    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node: ast.ImportFrom) -> None:
        if node.module == self.package_name:
            msg = self.error_message.format(
                path=self.path, lineno=node.lineno, col_offset=node.col_offset
            )
            sys.stdout.write(msg)
            sys.exit(1)
        super().generic_visit(node)


def import_from_submodules(package_name: str, content: str, path: str) -> None:
    tree = ast.parse(content)
    visitor = Visitor(package_name, path)
    visitor.visit(tree)


def main(argv: Sequence[str] | None = None) -> None:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("package_name")
    parser.add_argument("paths", nargs="*")
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    for path in args.paths:
        with open(path, encoding="utf-8") as fd:
            content = fd.read()
        import_from_submodules(args.package_name, content, path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This uses the `ast` module to parse the Python source code of every python file in the `package` directory and visits each `import <module>` and `from <module> import <function>` statement.
If the `<module>` part equals the package name (which is a command-line parameter of the script you can set in the pre-commit config), the position of the offending line is printed and the script exits with a nonzero exit code to indicate that there are errors.

Let's say there is a function `fun` inside `package/module/submodule.py`, which is also imported in `__init__.py` and included in `__all__`.
Inside `package/second_module/submodule.py` the following lines would raise an error if you run `pre-commit run import-from-submodules --all-files`:

```py
import package
from package import fun
from ..package import fun
```

whereas

```py
from package.module.submodule import fun
from ..module.submodule import fun
```

do not.
Note that the relative import examples illustrates that all leading dots of relative imports are ignored when comparing the module name to the given package name.

I hope this covers your use case. You are of course welcome to change the error message to something more helpful/clear. The `ast` module is extremely powerful, if you want to extend this code. For example the [use-pd_array-in-core](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ce3bac9af43838c7d690ee86e9bec4976a3303e3/scripts/use_pd_array_in_core.py) pre-commit hook mentioned earlier also flags all expressions `pd.array` by checking every attribute access.